# How to include tracker opencv headfiles via nugets package manager?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to build a tracker example program in opencv using Microsoft visual studio. I used `nuget` package manager to install the opencv. So I have below packages installed. Please refer the screenshot.
[image: nugets]

Other simple HelloWorld programme runs using package, but for tracking, I used the code from the [opencv example site](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/tracking/samples/tracker.cpp). 
I am getting error like while building itself. It says `#include<opencv2/tracking.hpp>` can't be found. Please find below screenshot, the error for other opencv lib is not present. So I am missing tracker source files, can you please help me how to add tracking.hpp into my project using NuGet Package manager?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tracking module is an OpenCV **contrib** module, so it's not present in the *"default package"*

You can use [opencvcontrib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/opencvcontrib/) with nuget.

---

Or you need to build OpenCV with contrib modules. It's quite simple and much more customizable. You can find a nice tutorial [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-windows/).